# Using cookies to stay signed in with third party login providers and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, asp.net-identity-2

I've followed [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) tutorial in an attempt to use several third party login providers with a simple ASP.NET MVC SPA application I am writing. While configuration is simple enough (I've actually enabled Twitter and Microsoft), and the sign-in process works correctly, the user credentials are stored in a browser session cookie only and do not persist across browser sessions.

I've also tried using the [alpha-1 sample project](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples&ei=demUU9CbJqS78AGuooC4Cw&usg=AFQjCNGDbrvapi6sRKkGFI9llNXPCsD6nA&sig2=6eHbnc6VqqnDI9k5rj24xg&bvm=bv.68445247,d.b2U&cad=rjt) from NuGet (with the same basic configuration applied) and it also does not work (at least in my environment).

The web application is only hosted locally (as I do not have an Azure account in which to test).

I thought the setting `ExpireTimeSpan` would affect it, but it does not:

```
 // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
app.UseCookieAuthentication(GetCookieAuthenticationOptions());


private static CookieAuthenticationOptions GetCookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    var options = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
        SlidingExpiration = true,
        CookieName = "MYSECURITY",
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(45.0),
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    };

    return options;
}
```

Cookies (I changed the default name of the cookie intentionally to validate that the code was executing -- it doesn't work with the default either):

[image: Cookies with session expiration]

Comment: There's another similar question which i answered here: [How to remember external logins][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180896/how-to-remember-the-login-in-mvc5-when-an-external-provider-is-used/23228005#23228005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVC Single Page Application project template in Visual Studio contains the following method in the `AccountController` which forces all all external logins to *not* be persistent across browser sessions:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    // ...
    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
    // ...
}
```

If you are comfortable with the security implications of trusting an identity that has been authenticated by an external provider across browser sessions, you could set `isPersistent = true` when calling `SignInAsync`.

Also be aware that any persistent login will be made non-persistent once the `SecurityStampValidator` fires the `regenerateIdentity` callback (which will occur after 20 minutes in your sample code above). See the question  *[ExpireTimeSpan ignored after regenerateIdentity / validateInterval duration in MVC Identity (2.0.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983726/expiretimespan-ignored-after-regenerateidentity-validateinterval-duration-in-m)* for discussion on this behavior.