# How to rewrite the OWIN-Cookie manually (MVC5)

Tags: cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I use the `IUserSecurityStampStore` to implement sign-out-everywhere functionality. It seems to work fine, however I have the problem that every time the user changes her password, she is logged off afterwards.

One possibility to work around this issue, is to call `SignIn` in the `Manage`-Action of the `AccountController` after a password change.

This seems to work, but I think it’s a bit clumsy and probably not the right way.

Thats why my questions are:

- How can I force OWIN to rewrite the cookie for the current logged on
  user?
- If the above way is the right way, how do I know if the user wants to
  have her Cookie persistent or not (SignIn desires this information)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the samples and templates call SignIn after the user does something that causes the security stamp to change.  Unfortunately you do not have a great way to restore the persistent state of the cookie in this scenario, this is something we will try address in a future update.

I filed an issue to track this along with the other related issues around this: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/135