# OnValidateIdentity disables the MVC OWIN remember me option

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

When I activate the OWIN logout-everywhere feature via security stamps and use the `OnValidateIdentity`-Callback of the `CookieAuthenticationProvider` with the `SecurityStampValidator`-class, the user is logged out every time he closes the browser.

```
provider.OnValidateIdentity =
    SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<MyUserManager, MyUser>(
        System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),(manager, user) => {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager);                                                       
        });
```

However, when I do the plumbing myself (lookup and comparison of the security stamps, rejecting or renewing the identity) in the `OnValidateIdentity`-callback, everything seems to work fine.

Is this a known bug, or do I miss here something? Or is there a good documentation about the `CookieAuthenticationProvider` and the use of `OnValidateIdentity`?
Digging with google only shows me some simple samples, but gives no further insight.

**Additional information**

- I use an own implementation of the UserStorage which saves all the
  data in a database
- I noted that every page request calls two times the
  GetSecurityStampAsync of the UserStorage, wheras when I use my
  implementation, only one call is done.
- Installed Identity Version is 2.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is resolved in ASP.NET Identity 2.2.  See https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2319

Answer (score 4):

This is basically a bug, the regeneration of the cookie should respect the current Remember Me option on the cookie.  As a workaround, you can copy the `OnValidateIdentity` code and feed in the current context properties to flow the Persistent mode through:

```
context.OwinContext.Authentication.SignIn(context.Properties, identity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following code in the disassembly of `SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity`:

```
// .. some other code
// ...
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = await regenerateIdentityCallback(userManager, tUser);
if (claimsIdentity != null){
context.get_OwinContext().get_Authentication().SignIn(new ClaimsIdentity[]
    {
       claimsIdentity
    });
}
```

It seems to me, that the `SignIn`-operation is incomplete and should set the remember-me option? Therefore I assume that the implementation of SecurityStampValidator is buggy.

Comment: My research and debugging shows that 'Ispersistent' is added as a claim on the user's identity.