# Persisting External Login using Asp.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have a WebForms app using external login (Microsoft and Google) and ASP.Net Identity 2.

I want the external login to persist when user comes back to the web site. Currently when user comes back they have to login again using the external provider.

I understand one way to do this is create persistent Application Cookie after locating the user like answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180896/how-to-remember-the-login-in-mvc5-when-an-external-provider-is-used/23228005#23228005) SO question.

But this is not acceptable since the requirement is that the user should be signed out if they sign out from the external provider.

If I create persistent "Application Cookie", Is there a way I can validate if  user is still logged in externally.

OR

Are there any other ways of achieving this?